# Django access array with forloop.counter in template

Tags: django, twig

I have an array `['one', 'two', 'three']`

In my django template i want to access to elements of the array like that:

```
{% for a in array %} 
  {{ array.loop.counter}}    
{% endif %}
```

But `array.loop.counter` return nothing.
There is a way to access the element of the array based on the loop counter of my for ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find a way to do it.

create a template tag into templatetags repository.

Use this custom filter:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='index')
def index(sequence, position):
    return sequence[position]
```

Then into the template :

```
{{ array|index:forloop.counter }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?:

```
{% for a in array %} 
  {{ a }}    
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Because not my usecase. My usercase is more complex than that, i tried to "schematize" to explain easier what i'm trying to do :)

Comment: Hmm ok, then this example doesn't capture that what you want to achieve unfortunately. For this example your workaround does exactly the same I think. Do you plan to shift the index and access a different element in the loop or something like that?